# Get Jquery value of Dropdownlist in User control created dynamically in placeholder

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, placeholder

I have a user control that contain a DropdownList.
I use this user control in a web form using a placeholder. I create this user control dynamically
I need to know, how can I get the selected value in the placeholder from the dropdownlist in JQuery when the dropdownlist change (Postback)?
This is my user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="IVT_DropDownList.ascx.cs" Inherits="Evi.Sc.Web.Evi.IVT.Sublayouts.IVT_DropDownList" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the place holder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhStatusClient" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

This is the codebehind:

```
IVT_DropDownList UC_StatusClients = (IVT_DropDownList)LoadControl("~/Evi/IVT/Sublayouts/IVT_DropDownList.ascx");

            IvtStatusClient ivtStatusClient = new IvtStatusClient();

            //Get the database to retrieve the information of the status
            var lstStatusClients = ivtStatusClient.Get_AllStatusClients();

            UC_StatusClients.DataSource = lstStatusClients;
            UC_StatusClients.InsertFirstRow = new ListItem("All", "0");
            plhStatusClient.Controls.Add(UC_StatusClients);
```

I’m trying with this , but doesn’t works.

```
$("#plhStatusClient").val()
```

Comment: The ID of the PlaceHolder is likely NOT the id of the HTML element since .Net generates element id's based on hierarchy. I didn't even look at the rest of it but I would check there first.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET renders ID's differently, try with `.ClientID`

```
$("#<%= plhStatusClient.ClientID %>").val()
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work this way. Have any other suggestions?

Comment: I try to catch the value an appear undefined.

Comment: This is the value that the compile retrieve: $('#<%= plhStatusClient.ClientID %>').val(): <not available>

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhStatusClient" runat="server" clientID="test">
</asp:PlaceHolder> // use client id  here i give an idea to use client id
```

**in jquery**

```
$("#test").val();
```

Comment: Hi, The ClientID doesn't appear to use it in the placeholder component. Give an error when I run the application.

Comment: I can not use ClienID in the Placeholder. I try to use ClienIDMode, but still not working.